# Morgan logger not recording date or time correctly

Tags: node.js, date, express, morgan, moment-timezone

The logger in my node.js app isn't recording the date or time correctly. I'm using morgan as the logging module, and moment-timezone to correctly record the date and time in my timezone (pacific stadard time). Yesterday, it was recording the date and time according to the format I set up, but today it isn't.

Here's the code for the morgan date token using moment-timezone:

```
morgan.token('date', (req, res, tz) => {
    return moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm a');
});
```

And here's the code where I use the date token in morgan.format():

```
morgan.format('logFormat', '[:date[America/Los_Angeles]], :resource, :remote-addr, :status, :response-time ms');
```

Yesterday, my requests were logging with this format:

[2018-07-31, 14:57 pm], hoopla, ::1, 401, 104.144 ms

Today everything is being logged like this:

[YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm a], hoopla, ::1, 401, 45.995 ms

The only change I made was adding new routes to the app, but each logging middleware is logging to a separate file, based on the route being used. Does anyone know why my date token isn't displaying the date anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `morgan.token('date'...` part with MomentJS logging the timezone looks all right to me!

I bet this is a syntactic error in the custom token format. If you don't need to pass a param, according to [the morgan docs](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#use-custom-token-formats), you can use custom token formats simply with semicolumn, like so `:date`. Therefore, try simply with:

```
morgan.format('logFormat', ':date, :resource, :remote-addr, :status, :response-time ms');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! There was definitely a syntactic error somewhere, most likely in the custom token definition in one of my route's index files. I commented out the morgan.token functions in the newly created routes, and the logs started recording the date/time correctly. Then, I went into each route's index file, made sure the token functions were correct, and made the logger active. Everything is working now with and without the timezone declared in :date. I wish I could explain what went wrong, but I'm still not sure, just happy that it's logging again.

Answer (score 1):

This question helps me solve my problem. Thanks!

This just works right for me:

```
morgan.token('date', (req, res, tz) => {
return moment().tz(tz).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
})
morgan.format('myformat', :date[Asia/Taipei] | :method | :url | :response-time ms');
    
app.use(morgan('myformat'))
```